# Don't dismiss NSAlert when button is clicked

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm showing an NSAlert with a custom view and three buttons. The custom view has two text fields and it allows the user to log in.

In the Mac App Store, an NSAlert with a similar design comes up. When the user clicks the sign in button, the NSAlert does not dismiss (until the credentials are verified). How does Apple keep the alert up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get the `NSButton` you want to behave differently. Change its target and action. (To call through to the original target/action, preserve them before you change them.)

```
NSAlert *alert = ...;
NSButton *button = [[alert buttons] objectAtIndex:...];

id oldTarget = [button target];
SEL oldAction = [button action];
[button setTarget:self];
[button setAction:@selector(verifyCredentials:)];
```

Alternatively, you may want to build the alert as a custom window controller and XIB (which is how Apple did it in the case of the App Store.) In that case, you have fine-grained control over button behaviour.

Comment: Great answer. It raises the point that the App Store _doesn't_ hack up an NSAlert, and explains how to do that, but also explains how to do what the OP thought he wanted, all very concisely and clearly.

Comment: How to dismiss within that method.

Comment: If you have a new question, you should ask a new question, not comment on an existing one.

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4 style

```
let alert = NSAlert()
alert.alertStyle = .informational
alert.messageText = "Y/N?"
alert.addButton(withTitle: "Y")
alert.addButton(withTitle: "N")

guard let window = view.window else { return } // for NSViewController

alert.beginSheetModal(for: window) { res in
    if res == .alertFirstButtonReturn {
        // "Y" action
    } else {
        // "N" action        
    }
}
```